# Предкомпилированные заголовки в QT

Tags: c++, linux, qt, makefile, qmake

Я собираю несколько проектов под Linux, и они используют один и тот же заголовок, pch.h.

Я добавляю в .pro-файл проекта test1 следующие строки

```
CONFIG += precompile_header
PRECOMPILED_DIR = $$DIR_SRC/Tools
PRECOMPILED_HEADER += $$DIR_SRC/Tools/dp_pch.h
```

Потом выполняю qmake и make.

После этого в Tools создается директория test1.gch, в которой лежит файл c++. Таким образом, предкомпилированный заголовок создается только для одного проекта, и при сборке следующего он будет компилироваться заново.

Как сделать так, чтобы при компиляции любого проекта заголовок создавался не индивидуально для этого проекта, а универсально для всех проектов? Хотелось бы чтобы создавался pch.gch рядом с обычным pch.h.